# How to stop Windows Update from offering to install "Games for Windows V3.0" repeatedly?

Tags: windows-vista, installation, windows-update

Windows Update keeps offering to install `Games for Windows V3.0`.  How do I get it to stop?

Comment: Thank you all very much... the manual install of GFWL solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the Games for Windows Live applications (I removed both "Microsoft Games for Windows - LIVE" and "Microsoft Games for Windows - LIVE Redistributable") from my computer, then downloading the installation program from the website and re-installing GFWL.

You can download the program here (scroll down to the big yellow button).

http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-us/aboutGFW/pages/gfw3intro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps have a previous version of that package installed?  It might not be wanting to perform a fresh install, but instead be trying to apply a mandatory update patch.

**Edit:** After looking at the German, I see that it's not "Wichtig"; "Important", but rather "empfehlen"; "Recommended".  I see the "Status" column says "erfolgreich"; "Successful".

**Edit<sup>2</sup>** I also note the column further to the right labeled "Installationsdatum"; "Installation date". My question stands. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old version and the update is just failing it might be worth downloading the latest version and doing a manual install.